# Get all comment and reply comment in single SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get a list of comments and reply comments from two tables in PostgreSQL.

```sql
-- Table comment
id | comment        | date_created |
1  | great course   | 20200102001  |
2  | awesome comment| 20200102002  |
3  | lorem comment  | 20200102003  |

-- Table comment reply
id | content           | commentid | date_created |
1  | great course 1    | 1         | 20200102004  |
2  | awesome comment 1 | 1         | 20200102005  |
3  | lorem comment 2   | 2         | 20200102006  |

-- Result expected:

id | comment           | date_created |
1  | great course      | 20200102001  |
1  | great course 1    | 20200102004  |
1  | awesome comment 1 | 20200102005  |
2  | awesome comment   | 20200102002  |
2  | lorem comment 2   | 20200102006  |
3  | lorem comment     | 20200102003  |
```

My question is how we can get all list comments in single SQL to pagination with SKIP and OFFSET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a simple UNION from the 2 tables.

```
select id, comment, date_created
  from comment
union 
select comment_id, content,date_created
  from comment_reply
 order by id, date_created;
```

As far as paging Postgres dose not have a SKIP (how does that differ than OFFSET anyway), but [LIMIT and OFFSET](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-limit.html)

```
select id, comment, date_created
  from comment
union 
select comment_id, content,date_created
  from comment_reply
 order by id, date_created
 limit &No_of_Rows    
offset &Skip;
```

Depending on your implementation you may want to wrap the query in a SQL function:

```
create or replace 
function show_comments_and_reply( offset_in integer  default 0 
                                , limit_in  integer  default null
                                ) 
  returns setof  comment 
 language sql
as $$
    select id, comment, created_date
      from comment
    union 
    select comment_id, content,created_date
      from comment_reply
     order by id, created_date
     limit limit_in    
    offset offset_in;
$$;
```

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=901f40b6881002f67ecd24d43188ca04).